# Clean Dirty data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In a data base the data is dirty, "date" is the Database is saved as a string and in different different formats.

I want to clean the data base and put it in a new database in which date would be in DATE sql format.

But the issue is that date in dirty date is in different formats
e.g.

```
14 sept 2012
14 SEPTEMBER 2012
14th sept 2012
14th sept 12
14 sept 12
etc
```

How to convert every date in single sql DATE format??

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Frank i am working in visual studio 2012 sql server

Comment: Is there any chance that some of the dates are stored as `02/08/2012`, for example, where that might represent more than one possible "clean" date? If so, there's no general solution to the problem.

Comment: I think you will do better to add some columns to your existing table and populate with your date string cut into pieces so you can clean up the individual components. Then when you select distinct values from each new column you will see what you are up against. e.g. Perhaps you may find other separators than spaces e.g. '14-SEP-2012', or you may find ambiguous values like 09/01/2012 01/09/2012 which depend on national settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
create table tmp_date(col1 varchar(100));

insert into tmp_date
VALUES('14 sept 2012'),('14 SEPTEMBER 2012'),('14th sept 2012'),('14th sept 12'),('14 sept 12')

select convert(datetime,left(col1,2)+'-'+lower(SUBSTRING(col1,CHARINDEX(' ',col1,1)+1,3))+'-'+ltrim(rtrim(reverse(LEFT(REVERSE(col1),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(col1),1)))))) from tmp_date
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all `date are later than or year 2000` and `two digits for date` and `at least 3 letters for month`, try this. [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/007c4/15)

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, '20' + right(mydate,2)+
                      CASE substring(mydate,charindex(' ', mydate,0)+ 1,3)
                           when 'jan' then '01'
                           when 'feb' then '02'
                           when 'mar' then '03'
                           when 'apr' then '04'
                           when 'may' then '05'
                           when 'jun' then '06'
                           when 'jul' then '07'
                           when 'aug' then '08'
                           when 'sep' then '09'
                           when 'oct' then '10'
                           when 'nov' then '11'
                           when 'dec' then '12'
                           else 'error' end +
                      left(mydate,2))
FROM t
```

**NOTE:** Solution is based on the given data samples

Comment: +1 in given situation it's as close as possible. It's impossible to convert date from random format anyway, OP have to define input formats he can parse.